# AWS Sagemaker using Batch Transfrom on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Sagemaker model trained and deployed and looking to run a Batch Transform on multiple files. 
I have a lambda function configured to run when a new file is uploaded to S3.
Currently, I have only seen ways to use the Invoke Endpoint function on lambda
i.e

```
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
message = ["On Wed Sep PDT Brent Welch said Hacksaw said W"]
response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName="sagemaker-scikit-learn-2020-02-05-13-44-45-011",
                                       ContentType='text/plain',
                                       Body=message)
json.loads(response['Body'].read())
```

However, i have multiple files that need to processed by the Sagemaker model.

I have code to create a transformer and run batch transform on multiple files

```
import sagemaker
training_job = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator.attach("{model_name")
transformer = training_job.transformer(instance_count=1,instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',strategy='MultiRecord',assemble_with='Line')

#batch_input_s3
transformer.transform(batch_input_s3)
print('Waiting for transform job: ' + transformer.latest_transform_job.job_name)
transformer.wait()
```

however, im unable to use this transformer code in a lambda since it requires the sagemaker library, which is over the size limit for zip file is 50mb

Comment: Looks like you want `create_transform_job` from the boto3 docs? 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_transform_job

Also an example here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-batch-transform.html

Comment: yes, thats it! thank you!!!

Comment: is there any difference between using  "import sagemaker  sagemaker.transformer.Transformer..."  and "client = boto3.client('sagemaker')
response = client.create_transform_job(..."  or is the same just from a diferent library?